# Why isn't my justify-content property working?

Tags: css, flexbox, spacing

I'm trying to add some space between the sidebar and content area of the template by applying the "justify-content" property to the parent div, but it's not adding that space between the sidebar and content area. I'm not sure what it is that I'm doing wrong.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex: 1 100%;
    width:92.5%;
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper article.content-main {
    flex: 6;
    order: 2;
}

#wrapper article.content-main section {
    background-color: rgba(149, 21, 130, 0.61);
    border: 2px solid #c31cd9;
    padding: 0.9em;
}

#wrapper aside {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0.4em;
    background-color: rgba(17, 208, 208, 0.56);
    border: 2px solid #15d0c3;
    position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>This is a placeholder <br />
            for header</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <article class="content-main">
            <section>
                <h2>Heading goes here...</h2>
                <time datetime="2014-05-21T02:43:00">Officialy Posted On May 21<sup>st</sup> 2:35 A.M.</time>
                <p>Content will go here...</p>
            </section>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <p>More content soon...</p>
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please make sure there is no clearfix or any pseudo code on the element

Comment: I had this. Turns out there is a conflict with bootstrap 3 grid utility functions. In particular: ```container:before, .container:after, .container-fluid:before, .container-sm:before, .container-md:before, .container-lg:before, .container-xl:before, .container-xxl:before, .container-fluid:after, .container-sm:after, .container-md:after, .container-lg:after, .container-xl:after, .container-xxl:after, .row:before, .row:after {
content: " ";
display: table;
}```

Answer (score 217, accepted):

`justify-content` *only* has an effect if there's space left over after your flex items have flexed to absorb the free space.  In most/many cases, there won't be any free space left, and indeed `justify-content` will do nothing.

Some examples where it *would* have an effect:

- if your flex items are all inflexible (`flex: none` or `flex: 0 0 auto`), and smaller than the container.
- if your flex items are flexible, BUT can't grow to absorb all the free space, due to a `max-width` on each of the flexible items.

In both of those cases, `justify-content` would be in charge of distributing the excess space.

In your example, though, you have flex items that have `flex: 1` or `flex: 6` with no `max-width` limitation. Your flexible items will grow to absorb all of the free space, and there will be no space left for `justify-content` to do anything with.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was able to find a simple fix though. I just added padding to the left side of the article container. Everything seems to work perfectly fine after that.

Comment: If there is text inside `justify-content` is useful regardless of the limitations pointed in this answer.

Comment: I think that margin: auto; will automatically fill space! Taking it out fixed my issue, after reading this post! Thank you!

Comment: damn! this worked

Answer (score 69):

What happened to me was I did NOT set `display: flex` on the container (the element with the `justify-content` property). Of course, `justify-content` won't work without that property.

Answer (score 17):

I had a further issue that foxed me for a while when theming existing code from a CMS. I wanted to use flexbox with `justify-content:space-between` but the left and right elements weren't flush.

In that system the items were floated and the container had a `:before` and/or an `:after` to clear floats at beginning or end. So setting those sneaky `:before` and `:after` elements to `display:none` did the trick.

Answer (score 14):

I was having a lot of problems with `justify-content`, and I figured out the problem was `margin: 0 auto`

The `auto` part overrides the `justify-content` so its always displayed according to the margin and not to the `justify-content`.

Comment: thanks, `margin-right: auto;` is important if using `justify-content: space-between;` as flex grids

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes `justify-content`  just isn't the property you should use. This is especially true when your `flex-direction` is `column` which makes the main axis vertical (y). You should try the `align-item` property, that may be the charm.

Answer (score 2):

There should be more space for `justify-content` to use.

You can use `flex-basis` and give a value, for example, 40 percent.

It's that simple

```
.content-main{
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
aside{
  flex-basis: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

always make sure to specify a `width` and `height` for your container + setting `padding : 0 (or auto) ;` and `margin : 0 (or auto) ;` for the elements inside the container might help too

Answer (score 0):

if,

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

doesn't work properly, make sure you:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
```

and then try

```
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height to a fixed value (100px or 30rem etc.) as opposed to a percentage or fill-available, that can be a fix. I don't think `justify-content: space-between` likes percentages (height:100%)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with 3 images first and last were stick to both ends and center one align as space between, so i did a trick using before and after now all the images are working as expected please check the code below for details.

HTML

```
<div className="flexContainer">
  <img src="image1.jpg" alt="..." />
  <img src="image2.jpg" alt="..." />
  <img src="image3.jpg" alt="..." />
</div>
```

My Css

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.flexContainer::before,
.flexContainer::after {
   content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find that there is clearly spacing but the elements will not bother move with `justify-content: space-around`, **add `width: 100%`** since the div/container can be limited to the width of each element, rather than its' full width.

Answer (score -12):

> [image: Screenshot]

Go to inspect element and check if .justify-content-center is listed as a class name under 'Styles' tab. If not, probably you are using bootstrap v3 in which justify-content-center is not defined.

If so, please update bootstrap, worked for me.