# flexbox refuses to justify content as i intended

Tags: css, flexbox

i am so confused about flexbox. i tried to use it to align some inputs in a simple form but it won't work the way i was intending. first i did this:

```
.container {
  width: 40vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and in html:

```
    <div class="container">
      <form id="location">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Location">
        <input type="submit" value="Get the weather!">
      </form>
    </div>
```

i was hoping the justify-content: space-between would add space between the two inputs so they floating out to the outer bounds of the container. not happening. after reading this: [justify-content property isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052569/justify-content-property-isnt-working) i tried the following:

```
.container {
  width: 40vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

and in html

```
    <div class="container">
      <form id="location">
        <div class="item"><input type="text" placeholder="Location"></div>
        <div class="item"><input type="submit" value="Get the weather!"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

now it looks even worse, because the divs are on top of each other, instead of next to each other. adding flex-direction: row doesn't change a thing. any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#location{
  width: 40vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <form id="location">
        <div class="item"><input type="text" placeholder="Location"></div>
        <div class="item"><input type="submit" value="Get the weather!"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

You have made `.container` div as your *flex-container*, which has only one flex-item `#location` form: You must make `#location` form your flex container so that it has two child elements to `space-between` your 400px width container And it will work fine

To brush up some fundamentals about flex-box visit: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If i understands correctly you need to add flexbox to parent. Your location is parent of the input elements.

```
.container {
 width: 40vw;
  #location   {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are targeting the wrong element.

Flex works on a parent of the element that you want to move.

You want to move elements of the `form`, so you should apply `flex` to your `form` tag instead of the `div.container`.

Because the `form` tag is also just a div, not an element to be moved.

Here is solution to your problem : https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/OJRmPVN

Answer (score 0):

Try use flex box for #location.
The parent of 2 inputs, are form not container.