# React Styled Components: Justify content does not work but align items & flex-direction do?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I added `justify-content: space-evenly` to a div in my React app, but I see no change. I have applied, `display: flex`, `align-items: flex-end`, and they all work as expected. I also tried `flex-direction` to check that was working, and it did. I don't understand why `justify-content` isn't working? I Have tried other values of `justify-content` such as `space-around`, `space-between` and `center`, but I had the same result, `justify-content` doesn't seem to work at all. Below is my code for the component and the parent styles the component inherits...

---- Component ----

```
// Libraries
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

// Components and icons
import { StyledTop } from "../Components/styles";
import {
  RecentlyPlayedIcon,
  SettingsIcon,
  QuitIcon,
} from "../Components/icons";

const RightBarButtons = () => {
  // Grab needed state and set vars
  const theme = useSelector((state) => state.theme);
  const rightBarState = useSelector((state) => state.rightBarSelection);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Handlers
  const buttonHandler = (buttonName) => {
    if (buttonName !== rightBarState) {
      dispatch({
        type: `SET_RIGHT_BAR_${buttonName.toUpperCase()}`,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <StyledTopButtons>
      <button>
        <QuitIcon theme={theme} />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          buttonHandler("settings");
        }}
        style={{
          borderLeft: `4px solid ${
            theme === "light" ? "rgba(0,0,0,.05)" : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125)"
          } `,
          borderRight: `4px solid  ${
            theme === "light" ? "rgba(0,0,0,.05)" : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125)"
          } `,
        }}
      >
        <SettingsIcon rightBarState={rightBarState} theme={theme} />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          buttonHandler("recently_played");
        }}
      >
        <RecentlyPlayedIcon rightBarState={rightBarState} theme={theme} />
      </button>
    </StyledTopButtons>
  );
};
const StyledTopButtons = styled(StyledTop)`
  margin: 3.9rem 4rem;
  width: calc(100% - 8rem);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  button {
    transform: translateX(-2.6rem);
    height: 2.2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    svg {
      height: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
`;

export default RightBarButtons;
```

---- `StyledTop` component, that I am inheriting from ----

```
export const StyledTop = styled.div`
  height: 2.8rem;
  width: 100%;

  h1 {
    margin: 4rem;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: ${(props) => (props.theme === "light" ? "black" : "white")};
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  span {
    color: #3ca8c9;
  }
`;
```

If someone could help me figure out why this isn't behaving as expected I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, I pretty don't understand why it's happening. I tried to copy your components from scratch except the logic, and it seems working fine...
https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-test-ilfr7

Comment: @RichardZhan Thanks for having a look, and including the sandbox link. I'll try again tomorrow morning and report back!

Comment: Hello @user15459167 does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052569/justify-content-property-isnt-working

Comment: Hey, @PriyankKachhela, that did help point me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: @RichardZhan I just put the answer up below. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. After looking at @RichardZhan sandbox code, I decided to remove the icons and just have plain text inside of the buttons. This solved the problem instantly, meaning the problem arose from the icons. I applied a static width to the icons and this worked. The value of the width is the same as the height, that way the icons remain square.

Below is my code for the component, in the styled components section at the bottom, you can see the definition of the width and height for the buttons and svgs inside of the buttons.

```
// Libraries
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

// Components and icons
import { StyledTop } from "../Components/styles";
import {
  QuitIcon,
  SettingsIcon,
  RecentlyPlayedIcon,
} from "../Components/icons";

const RightBarButtons = () => {
  // Grab needed state and set vars
  const theme = useSelector((state) => state.theme);
  const rightBarState = useSelector((state) => state.rightBarSelection);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Handlers
  const buttonHandler = (buttonName) => {
    if (buttonName !== rightBarState) {
      dispatch({
        type: `SET_RIGHT_BAR_${buttonName.toUpperCase()}`,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <StyledRightBarTop>
      <button>
        <QuitIcon theme={theme} />
      </button>
      <ButtonBreak />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          buttonHandler("settings");
        }}
      >
        <SettingsIcon rightBarState={rightBarState} theme={theme} />
      </button>
      <ButtonBreak />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          buttonHandler("recently_played");
        }}
      >
        <RecentlyPlayedIcon rightBarState={rightBarState} theme={theme} />
      </button>
    </StyledRightBarTop>
  );
};

const StyledRightBarTop = styled(StyledTop)`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  button {
    height: 2.4rem;
    svg {
      height: 100%;
      // static width, matching the height, keeping correct dimensions for the SVG and button
      width: 2.4rem;
    }
  }
`;

const ButtonBreak = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.2rem;
  background: blue;
`;

export default RightBarButtons;
```